# How do you define that a user who is not logged in or not logged into the account will not be able to see the main menu in angular?

Tags: angular

I would love to know what I need to write to get a user who is not registered to the app or who is not logged in to see the main menu screen just after signing in. I created a nav.component.html that displays the menu:

Comment: Please provide some code and describe what you have tried to solve the problem !

Answer (score 0):

Create an AuthGuard for that and in the route, activate it.